# Filter or smoothen serial noise data using python

Tags: python, serialization, matplotlib, filtering, smoothing

I am trying to smooth/filter data from USB to serial. The data contains force value from two servos. It's not showing exact X and Y direction now. So I need a use full example code to smooth/filter my data from serial port
My function which gives the data from serial is given below

```
def get_force(self):

    torque1 = self.servo1.get_servo_torque()
    torque2 = self.servo2.get_servo_torque()
    angle1, angle2 = self.get_jointpos()

    angle1 = math.radians(angle1)
    angle2 = math.radians(angle2)

    A=-(L1*math.cos(angle1)+L2*math.cos(angle1+angle2))
    B=L1*math.sin(angle1)+L2*math.sin(angle1+angle2)
    C=L2*math.sin(angle1+angle2)
    D=L2*math.cos(angle1+angle2)


    self.a = np.array([[A, B], [C, D]])
    ainv = inv(self.a)
    #print np.allclose(np.dot(self.a, ainv), np.eye(2))

    #print np.allclose(np.dot(ainv, self.a), np.eye(2))

    #F=[F1,F2]
    c = ainv

    b = [torque1, torque2]
    F=np.dot(c, b)

    #print F[0] 

    self.G=F[0]
    self.H=F[1]
    return(self.G,self.H)
```

I want to filter the G and H data and plot in matplotlib animation .....Expecting sample code and useful link.

Comment: are the two return values both scalars?

Comment: It is float values and vector

Comment: @ballsdotballs it contains negative values too

Comment: What data are you wanting to smooth?  You need to post some example data that shows exactly what signal you want to filter.

Comment: Scipy has filters and other signal processing tools: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html